# install cellranger software in ubuntu

Tags: installation

```html
export PATH=/opt/cellranger-3.1.0:$PATH
vim ~/.bashrc
export PATH="~/opt/cellranger-3.1.0:$PATH"

These codes work.
```

I want to install cellranger in Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Best,

Yue

https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/installation](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/installation

export PATH=/opt/cellranger-3.1.0:$PATH
   vim ~/.bashrc
   export PATH="~/opt/cellranger-3.1.0:$PATH"

Comment: 'export PATH=/opt/cellranger-3.1.0:$PATH'
      ' vim ~/.bashrc'
        export PATH="~/opt/cellranger-3.1.0:$PATH"'

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, it is already installed. just run the command below as they described and check if the output is the same as theirs. You can start using cellranger after that.

```html
$ cellranger testrun --id=tiny
```

The output must be as follows:

```html
cellranger testrun 3.1.0
Copyright (c) 2016 10x Genomics, Inc.  All rights reserved.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Martian Runtime - v3.2.3
 
Running preflight checks (please wait)...
2016-11-14 09:57:51 [runtime] (ready)           ID.tiny.SC_RNA_COUNTER_CS.SC_RNA_COUNTER.SETUP_CHUNKS
2016-11-14 09:57:54 [runtime] (split_complete)  ID.tiny.SC_RNA_COUNTER_CS.SC_RNA_COUNTER.SETUP_CHUNKS
...
 
Pipestance completed successfully!
```